EventListner not wokring in Swing
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


class MainWindow extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ChangeListener {

    JLabel j;
    JLabel s1;
    int speed;
    JSlider s;
    MainWindow(){
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Todo Application");
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.addKeyListener(this);



        s = new JSlider(0,25,10);
        s.setLocation(50, 10);
        s.setSize(400, 100);
        s.addChangeListener(this);
        this.add(s);

        speed=s.getValue();

        s1 = new JLabel();
        s1.setText("Speed: " + speed);
        s1.setLocation(200, 50);
        s1.setSize(100,100);
        this.add(s1);

        j = new JLabel();
        j.setSize(100, 100);
        j.setBackground(Color.red);
        j.setOpaque(true);
        j.setLocation(200, 200);
        this.add(j);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
            case 'w' -> j.setLocation(j.getX(), j.getY() - speed);
            case 'd' -> j.setLocation(j.getX() + speed, j.getY());
            case 's' -> j.setLocation(j.getX(), j.getY() + speed);
            case 'a' -> j.setLocation(j.getX() - speed, j.getY());
            default -> System.out.println(speed);
        }
        System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        speed = s.getValue();
        s1.setText("Speed: " + speed);
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainWindow();
    }
}

It was working when i used keyPressEvent and ChnageEvent Independently but when i combine both it doesnt work. The Label doesnt move even though deafult speed is 10, and the label displaying the speed doesnt appear at all.

when you click on the slider, it gets the focus, that is, it will receive the key events instead of the frame - try s.setFocusable(false) (testing only, not the recommended solution)

I modified the code you posted to get the following GUI.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.
All Swing applications must start with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the Event Dispatch Thread.
Swing has a nifty container called a JPanel.  I created a control JPanel for the JSlider and speed JLabel.  I created a moveable JPanel for the moving JLabel.  By creating two JPanels, I separated my concerns and I was able to focus on one part of the GUI at a time.
I had to use key bindings rather than a KeyListener because I could not get focus on the moveable JPanel.
Here's the complete runnable code.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class SpeedDisplay implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SpeedDisplay());
    }

    private int speed, x, y;

    private JLabel speedLabel, square;

    public SpeedDisplay() {
        this.speed = 10;
        this.x = 150;
        this.y = 150;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Todo Application");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createControlPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(createMoveablePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 25, speed);
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
                speed = slider.getValue();
                speedLabel.setText("Speed: " + speed);
            }
        });
        panel.add(slider, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        speedLabel = new JLabel();
        speedLabel.setText("Speed: " + speed);
        panel.add(speedLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createMoveablePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        createKeyBindings(panel);

        square = new JLabel();
        square.setSize(100, 100);
        square.setBackground(Color.red);
        square.setOpaque(true);
        square.setLocation(x, y);
        panel.add(square);

        return panel;
    }

    private void createKeyBindings(JPanel panel) {
        InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "up");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "down");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "left");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "right");

        actionMap.put("up", new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                y -= speed;
                square.setLocation(x, y);
            }
        });

        actionMap.put("down", new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                y += speed;
                square.setLocation(x, y);
            }
        });

        actionMap.put("left", new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x -= speed;
                square.setLocation(x, y);
            }
        });

        actionMap.put("right", new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x += speed;
                square.setLocation(x, y);
            }
        });
    }

}


thank you, do you have any resources for learning making games with swing ?

@Sunny Reddy: Here's a free, downloadable version of the book I learned from.  Fundamental 2D Game Programming with Java by Timothy Wright.  The "download templates" link is the correct download link.
